# How to make "Dual List Box plugin for jQuery and Bootstrap" dynamic?

Tags: jquery, listbox, yii2-advanced-app

I want a [dual list box](https://github.com/Geodan/DualListBox/) to be dynamic. For example when a user clicks a certain link, a method will be called and then get the list from the database and then these data will be displayed in the modal. The problem is that it only works in the first run. When I refresh the page it works again once.

Here is my code so far.

```
            function gettype2(id){
                $('#duallist').bootstrapDualListbox('destroy');
                $.post('" . yii::$app->request->baseUrl . "/accounts/gettype2',{'id':id},function(data){
                    $('#duallist').html(data);
                    var demo1 = $('#duallist').bootstrapDualListbox({infoTextFiltered: '<span class=\"label label-purple label-lg\">Filtered</span>'});
            var container1 = demo1.bootstrapDualListbox('getContainer');
            container1.find('.btn').addClass('btn-white btn-info btn-bold');
                });
            }
```

I am making a user role permission page.

[image]

First click of the edit link. (working fine)

[image]

Second click. Does not work correctly.

[image]

Comment: I have a Question .. How you display the database value in right side option box???

Comment: @NadimulDeCj just make it selected. `<option selected="">admin</option>` that way the list will go to the right.

Comment: ok thanks for your help ... i will try it ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by removing the select tag in the body of the modal and then I added an empty div tag. Then this code.

```
function gettype2(id){
                    $('#sample').html('<select multiple=\"multiple\" size=\"10\" name=\"duallistbox_demo1\" id=\"duallist\"></select>');
                    $('#duallist').bootstrapDualListbox('destroy');
                    $.post('" . yii::$app->request->baseUrl . "/accounts/gettype2',{'id':id},function(data){
                        $('#duallist').html(data);
                        var demo1 = $('#duallist').bootstrapDualListbox({infoTextFiltered: '<span class=\"label label-purple label-lg\">Filtered</span>'});
                var container1 = demo1.bootstrapDualListbox('getContainer');
                container1.find('.btn').addClass('btn-white btn-info btn-bold');
                    });
                }
```